# What is XML Schema metadata?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, metadata

I am currently working on the assignment but I do not understand what is meant by 'metadata'

One element in my XML Schema must be:

when entry last was updated: date and time (metadata)

I do know that the type used for date and time can be something like

xsi:dateTime but I do not know what is meant by metadata.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "metadata" is used in two different senses by different communities.

In the database community, metadata usually means type or schema information; "the metadata" is virtually synonymous with "the schema".

In the document community, metadata usually means information associated with a document that is not part of the document content, for example the provenance of the document, or its access control rules.

The person who wrote this comment was using the term in the second sense: the date and time of last update of some information is instance-level information that is not part of the primary content.

Comment: so is this referring to the attribute in the XML context instead of having an element?

Comment: it's common to represent metadata using XML attributes, but the term "metadata" is about the semantics of the information, not its syntactic representation.